# SQL: query returning complementary values

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Here's a simplified version of my problem. I have a table containing names and a table containing a limited list of time slots (let's say days of the week) A linker table links these two tables. Using a simple inner join of those three tables I can show the availability of each individual:

```
| id   | day |
|******|*****|
| 1    | MO  |
| 1    | TU  |
| 1    | WE  | 
| 1    | TH  |
| 1    | FR  |
| 1    | SU  | 
| 2    | MO  |  
| 2    | TU  |
| 2    | WE  | 
| 2    | FR  |
| 2    | SA  |
| 2    | SU  |
```

Because most users are available most of the time, I would like to run a query to show when they are *not* available:

```
| id   | day |
|******|*****|
| 1    | SA  |
| 2    | TH  |
```

I know how to find the complement of a set using outer join and WHERE ... IS NULL, but I cannot see how I can then link these complementary values to individuals. This is probably something very obvious but I have been stuck on it for a couple of hours. Please note that I have no control over the DB design.

EDIT: I apologize for my question not being clear enough.

I'll give it another try.

The table individuals has the following columns: id (PK), first_name, last_name, DOB, etc.
The table timeslots has the following columns: id (PK), timeslot
The linker table individualstimeslots has the following columns: id (PK), idindividual (FK), idtimeslot (FK)

The following query returns an overview of the  timeslots when an individual is available.

```
SELECT 
i.first_name, i.last_name, t.timeslot
FROM 
individuals as i 
inner join individualstimeslots as it on it.idindividual = i.id
inner join timeslots as t on t.id = it.idtimeslot
```

(results would be similar to the first table above except with first and last name instead of id)

If I wanted to find out when the individual with id 1 is not available I could use the following query:

```
SELECT 
i.first_name, i.last_name, t.timeslot, t2.timeslot as all
FROM 
individuals as i 
inner join individualstimeslots as it on it.idindividual = i.id and i.id = 1
inner join timeslots as t on t.id = it.idtimeslot
right outer join timeslots as t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

with the following result:

```
| JOHN | DOE | MO | MO | 
| JOHN | DOE | TU | TU | 
| JOHN | DOE | WE | WE | 
| JOHN | DOE | TH | TH | 
| JOHN | DOE | FR | FR | 
|      |     |    | SA | 
| JOHN | DOE | MO | SU |
```

If I want to show only the time slot when John Doe is not available, I could add the following condition to the query:

```
WHERE t.timeslot IS NULL
```

result:

```
|      |     |    | SA |
```

This result however does not explicitly refer to the individual with id = 1.
What I am after is a query which does just that and shows for *all* (selected) individuals when they are *not* available:

```
| JOHN | DOE | SA |
| JANE | DOE | TH |
```

Hope I have made myself clearer now.

Comment: Can you explain this part *how I can then link these complementary values to individuals*

Comment: I believe a `Cross Join` between the individual's table and the time slots table compared to the query you already have would get you what you want, but it's almost 100% impossible to say since I have no idea what your data looks like. Can you share sample data from your tables and the SQL query you are currently using to get the first results above.

Comment: Post a data sample for each table and we will come with a nice query :) Without it its just impossible.

Comment: Why not create a table of all available days? Then a query from that table and left join your current table where your current table is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query seems to do what you would like. You could probably even rewrite this without the CTE, but I think it makes it clearer.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.days (namedays) VALUES 
('Monday'),
('Tuesday'),
('Wednesday'),
('Thursday'),
('Friday'),
('Saturday'),
('Sunday')

INSERT INTO availability (ID,namedays) VALUES
(1,'Monday'),
(1,'Tuesday'),
(1,'Thursday'),
(2,'Monday'),
(2,'Saturday')

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID AS ID ,d.namedays FROM availability a
CROSS JOIN dbo.days d)

SELECT CTE.ID, CTE.namedays FROM CTE
LEFT OUTER JOIN availability a
ON a.ID = CTE.ID AND a.namedays = CTE.namedays
WHERE a.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you can get away with a simple query for this (I would like to be proven wrong, though).
But you could easily create a cursor that loops through all of the (relevant) individuals and for each of them does the outer join query. You could then insert the results into a temporary table and select from that at the end.
You've tagged both mysql and sql-server, so I don't know which language you use. But it's possible in both :)